# Turn a string of '"a", "b", "c"' into an array of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string

**Please read the specifics below:**
I have a string array as so:

```
string[] data = new string[] { "word1", "word2", "word3" };
```

I'm trying to put a STRING variable, which will include the "word1", "word2", "word3" data, inside of the string array.
In other words, I want the string array to look as so:

```
SingleStringHere = "\"word1\", \"word2\", \"word3\"";
string[] data = new string[] { SingleStringHere };
```

**The 'SingleStringHere' variable will be retrieving data off of a server, which will be used in the string array. The string array will be formatted and encrypted properly, in order to be sent in a packet through a socket.**

***No errors are given with the code, however, data in the 'SingleStringHere' variable is not being read as separate strings. I do NOT want to put the retrieved server data into a string array, because that will be TOO MUCH parsing!***

Comment: Why would there be errors? The code is equivalent to new `string[] { "\"word1\", \"word2\", \"word3\"" };`

Comment: Please read the below text, "No errors are given with the code, however...".

Comment: So go back to what the equivalent code *means*. Then compare that with that is being asked for and the assumption-restriction.

Comment: I need the equivalent code (string) INSIDE of the string array. The array is not reading the string as separate strings, so it isn't being encrypted/formatted properly for packet sending.

Comment: Why would it? Never told it.

Comment: And that's what I'm asking help on...

Comment: Then just ask that - no point to wallow through everything else.

Comment: In any case, if the words *cannot* contain commas use Split-on-comma and Select the text between the wrapping parentehesi.

Comment: Most people like an explanation of what one is trying to do with a code, for better understanding. No need to complain, I'm simply trying to ask a question.

Comment: try SingleStringHere.Split(',');

Answer (score 1):

If the strings that you receive don't contain commas, you could do something as simple as this:

```
string SingleStringHere = "\"word1\", \"word2\", \"word3\"";
string[] data = SingleStringHere.Replace("\"").Split(',');
```

Otherwise, you're going to have to do some more complex parsing. Something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      string SingleStringHere = "\"word1\", \"word2\", \"word3\"";
      string[] data = ParseSingleString(SingleStringHere);
      foreach(string s in data)
      {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
      }
}

public static string[] ParseSingleString(string singleString)
{
      List<string> multipleStrings = new List<string>();
      StringBuilder current = new StringBuilder();
      bool inQuote = false;
      for(int index = 0; index < singleString.Length; ++index) // iterate through the string
      {
            if (singleString[index] == '"')
            {
                   inQuote = !inQuote;
            }
            else if (!inQuote && singleString[index] == ',') // split at comma if not in quote
            {
                   multipleStrings.Add(current.ToString().Trim());
                   current.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                   current.Append(singleString[index]);
            }
      }
      multipleStrings.Add(current.ToString()); // don't forget the last one
      return multipleStrings.ToArray();
}
```

If the strings can contain quotes, it can get trickier. That's just my rough example.

Be warned that this operation might be memory-intensive with all of the string copying and so forth (I count about 3 copies for each substring). You may be able to circumvent some of this by recording the indices of the first and last character in one of the strings, and then taking a substring on the entire `singleString`. Also note that `List<string>` has to be copied into an array before it returns. You may want to just return an `IEnumerable<string>` instead, or even an `IList<string>`. But it's late, and I think the above is sufficient for this question.

*P.s. I'm on a Linux machine right now without access to a C# compiler, so I apologize for any typos.*

Answer (score 1):

You can get array from formatted string like this

```
string SingleStringHere = "\"word1\", \"word2\", \"word3\"";
String[] arr = SingleStringHere.Split(',');
```

Comment: Why the cast to `String[]`? `String.Split()` returns a string array already.